# getting the index of the select_tag selected value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select_tag on my search page i.e below:

```
<p><%= @blah %> hello</p>
    <%= form_for :search, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :search } do |f| %>
    <table width="100%">
          <tr>
             <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;" width="35%">
                <h2 style="color:Black; font-size: x-large;">Specs</h2>               
             <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="center">
                      <%= select_tag 'Interest', 
                      options_from_collection_for_select(@students, :id, :student_mentor_subjects) %>
                   </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
    <% end %>
```

And I want to get the index of the selected value and its working fine but when I get it into a variable like below:

```
def search     
     @blah = params[:Interest]
end
```

and when i pick the value of `@blah` in the view page at this line `<p><%= @blah %> hello</p>` then its not showing me the index of the selected value of select_tag in the `@blah` variable.
Kindly, help me,waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: can you kindly post all the params variable here.

Comment: you can also do params[:Interest] in view page

Comment: Do you also care about the value of what is selected, or only the index in the list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3301201/hassan-ali-khan Is this also your profile? If so, you shouldn't be maintaining multiple profiles on SO.It is against the community.

Comment: Are you trying to do it without refreshing the page? If so, you have to send it Via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to specify the selected entry in:

```
                <%= select_tag 'Interest', 
                  options_from_collection_for_select(@students, 
                       :id, 
                       :student_mentor_subjects,
                       @blah
                ) %>
```

see [Rails API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)